# Calculating p-value associated with a slope in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, statistics, p-value

In postgres I am calculating an R2 and a slope using the below functions:

```
regr_r2(y,x)
regr_slope(y,x)
```

Is there any way to calculate the p-value associated to the slope within postgres?

Comment: Not directly, AFAIK. Use the pl/Python or pl/R plugins to use Python or R within Postgres and make all these statistical analyses easier.